# Android ZXing waiting time after decoding an image

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing, barcode-scanner

I'm using the ZXing project on an Android application, with the IntentIntegrator method (so the Barcode Scanner app is opened whenever I need to do a scan).

I've noticed that capturing and decoding the image takes almost no time (less than a second), but then it stays with the image captured as a top layer with ~50% transparency for about 2-3 seconds, before sending the scanned information back to my application.

Is this a normal behavior when the library is not embedded into the project or there's something I can do to decrease that waiting time?

Comment: I have the same issue; did you ever solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Nope, it seems it's part of the library

Comment: How you have done it fast? Can you post your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an old post, but since it doesn't have an answer, let me answer it.

You can set the delay after the scan adding an extra to the intent, like:

```
IntentIntegrator intentIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator();
intentIntegrator.addExtra("RESULT_DISPLAY_DURATION_MS", 500L);//A long is expected
//all the rest of the code
```

The constant is defined in the class `com.google.zxing.integration.android.Intents`

Comment: Thanks! I've had to develop an upgrade to the app and tried this out, it works like a charm.